# How can I store PID into a file

Tags: pidfile

I need to store the pid number in a file/files. How to do it?

Comment: You want to store a process ID in a file. What process' PID do you want to store, and why?

Comment: How do you have the PID number right now? A variable? By looking it up based on a process name?

Answer (score 2):

PID files can be created by the process itself or by a helper program, which writes a PID file after starting the main program.

On Unix-like systems, new programs are often created using `fork()` and `exec()` system calls. `fork()` creates a copy of the calling process, returning child's process ID (PID) in parent and 0 in the child. The parent process (helper program) can save the PID in a PID file. `exec()` is then used  to launch the new program.

The process can get its own PID using `getpid()` system call and then saves it to a file.

If you are starting a program from the shell, you could use a helper program such as `start-stop-daemon` (if on a Debian-based system), which can write a PID file after starting the program. If your program demonizes itself, you can also store the PID from the shell by accessing the `$$` variable.

Comment: ... and a shell can use `"$$"`.

Comment: `exec` does not create a new process.